# Метод change_password библиотеки dx auth для CodeIgniter не может корректно сравнить пароли

Tags: codeigniter

Я новичок, работаю с Codeigniter и для авторизации на моём сайте была выбрана библиотека  dx auth. Всё работало вполне хорошо, пока не дошло до настройки смены пароля.

Суть проблемы заключается в том, что стандартная форма библиотеки всё время выдаёт ошибку: "Неверный старый пароль". Я подозреваю, что проблема в шифровании пароля, который вводится пользователем для проверки. Сам метод в контроллере выглядит так:

```
<? php  function change_password($old_pass, $new_pass){
    // Load Models
    $this->ci->load->model('dx_auth/users', 'users');

    // Default return value
    $result = FAlSE;

    // Search current logged in user in database
    if ($query = $this->ci->users->get_user_by_id($this->ci->session->userdata('DX_user_id')) AND $query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        // Get current logged in user
        $row = $query->row();

        $pass = $this->_encode($old_pass);

        // Check if old password correct
        if (password_verify($pass, $row->password))
        {
            // Crypt and encode new password
            $new_pass = password_hash($new_pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

            // Replace old password with new password
            $this->ci->users->change_password($this->ci->session->userdata('DX_user_id'), $new_pass);

            // Trigger event
            $this->user_changed_password($this->ci->session->userdata('DX_user_id'), $new_pass);

            $result = TRUE;
        }
        else 
        {
            $this->_auth_error = $this->ci->lang->line('auth_incorrect_old_password');
        }
    }

    return $result;
} ?>
```

В конфигурации никакого ключа шифрования нет, поэтому если я всё правильно понял, один и тот же пароль хэшируется каждый раз по-разному.

Вопрос: где мне найти ключ шифрования? Или решение задачи в чём-то другом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась отправкой в password_verify переменной $old_pass напрямую, в обход метода _encode